# Browsing files within iphone application

Tags: iphone

I have problem to browse different types of file.

I know browse music file and Photo from iPhone but i want to browse all typs of file doc,zip,ppt,xls,pdf files within a application. like music and photo library.

Is there any way to browse all types of files?

Thanks you,

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean browse "all types of files"? Files on the device itself? If so, you can only access files within your application's sandbox. You can get a list of a directory using `NSFileManager` and then render the results into a `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSFileManager to browse the files in your application's little sandbox, but you're gonna have to work out a way to get the files there first (download or whatever), provided you don't include them with the application. If you want to interact with the files then you're in another ball game.